# Where is the unit after a calculation?

Tags: units

I was playing with some of the new features, and when I type e.g.

```
Quantity[10, "ml"] + Quantity[250 - 100, "ml"]
```

I get

```
160 mL
```

as expected.

But when I want to solve the following equation

```
Solve[Quantity[x, "ml"] Quantity[5, "mol"] + Quantity[250 - x, "ml"] Quantity[7, "mol"] ==
Quantity[250, "ml"] Quantity[6, "mol"], x]
```

I get

```
{{x -> 125}}
```

without any unit. But x actually is in mL. So I'm wondering what I am getting wrong, i.e. why don't I get mL here?

thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

x is not in mL..it is just a pure number. `Quantity[x, "ml"]` is the 'thing' that is in mL.

To get what you want, you need to recast your Solve command as

```
Solve[x Quantity[5, "mol"] + (Quantity[250, "ml"] - x) Quantity[7, 
     "mol"] == Quantity[250, "ml"] Quantity[6, "mol"], x]
```

However, the result is a bit strange looking.

```
{{x -> Quantity[1/8000, ("Meters")^3]}}
```

It is, however, correct.  Let's convert it to numerical form

```
Solve[
  x Quantity[5, "mol"] + (Quantity[250, "ml"] - x) Quantity[7, 
      "mol"] == Quantity[250, "ml"] Quantity[6, "mol"], x] // N
```

gives

```
{{x -> Quantity[0.000125, ("Meters")^3]}}
```

Which looks right since 1 mL= 0.000001 m^3

How to force Mathematica to stick to mL, however, is another question.

Of course you could get back to mL by using `UnitConvert`.  For example

```
UnitConvert[
 x /. Solve[
    x Quantity[5, "mol"] + (Quantity[250, "ml"] - x) Quantity[7, 
        "mol"] == Quantity[250, "ml"] Quantity[6, "mol"], 
    x] [[1]], "Milliliters"]
```

gives

```
Quantity[125, "Milliliters"]
```

Comment: Not strange at all! UnitConvert[Quantity[1/8000, ("Meters")^3], "Milliliters"] = 125 mL.

Comment: agreed. Perhaps I should have said 'unexpected' because one might like like to remain in Milliliters.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to get used to Quantity a little more.